# call a java method that asks the user for the number of employees in the company(no parameter and return as value >= 0)

Tags: java

I want to display the statement inside the else whenever the user type a negative number, I know this while loop will be infinite loop but I don't know how to break it. I try to type in "break", but it shows error:

> need a return statement.

Should I use only if-statement or am I writing the right code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class number{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        workers();
        int numEmployee;
    }
    public static int workers(){
        System.out.println("How many employees do you have?");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = input.nextInt();

        int numEmployee;
        while(true){
            if(number >= 0){
                numEmployee = number;
                return numEmployee;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Please enter a positive number");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the user supplying the values repeatedly or just once.?

Comment: Please can you indent your code? It is currently very hard to read.

Comment: This is the first I ask a question, so I don't really know how to put my code in.

Comment: while(number > 0) should work. Put the sysout outside while loop.

Comment: the user only type in once

Comment: Q: Why not `int numEmployee workers();`?  Q: Does reordering the code actually solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested changes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

// Always capitalize your public class name (and the corresponding source file)
public class Number{

  public static void main(String[] args){
    // Get #/employees
    int numEmployee = Number.workers();
    System.out.println ("#/employees=" + numEmployee);
  }

  public static int workers(){
    // Loop until we get a valid number
    int number;
    do {
      System.out.println("How many employees do you have?");  
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      number = input.nextInt();
    } while (number <= 0)

    // Return the final value
    return number;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing you want is to ask for input every loop. Also, you should have a return in your method for every condition. A compiler doesn't know your loop is infinite so it expects a return:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Number{

  public static void main(String[] args){
    int numEmployee = workers();
    System.out.println("Number of empoyees: " + numEmployee);
  }

  public static int workers(){
    int number = 0;

    System.out.println("How many employees do you have?");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true){
      number = input.nextInt();
      if(number >= 0){
        return number;
      }else{
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive number");
      }
    }
    return 0; //Added this
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method should be:

```
public static int workers() {
    System.out.println("How many employees do you have?");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number;
    boolean isValid = false;

    int numEmployee = 0;
    while (!isValid) {
        number = input.nextInt();
        if (number >= 0) {
            numEmployee = number;
            isValid = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive number");
        }
    }

    return numEmployee;
}
```